# filling a select field with model with certain tag - laravel

Tags: mysql, forms, laravel, collections, laravel-5.1

I have no problem with selecting a model tagged with certain tag

```
        $lis = Capacitytype::find(124)->entities()->orderBy('name','asc')->get();
```

In my `Capacitytype` model I have this relation:

```
public function entities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Entity', 'entity_capacitytypes', 'capacitytype_id', 'entity_id');
}
```

MY PROBLEM:
I wish to use the same selection f models to fill a select field in a form. (I use select2.js)

When I try to implement this code

```
        $lis = array(null => 'Commitee') + Capacitytype::find(124)->entities()->orderBy('name','asc')->lists('name', 'id')->all();
```

I get this error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `name`, `id` from `entities` inner join `entity_capacitytypes` on `entities`.`id` = `entity_capacitytypes`.`entity_id` where `entities`.`deleted_at` is null and `entity_capacitytypes`.`capacitytype_id` = 6 order by `name` asc)

I tried to solve this issue by adding table name to my code, but this is as far as I was able to go: 
`->lists('entities.name', 'entities.id')`

**My Question:** 
how modify the code to get the desired collection for my select field?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of Laravel's `with()` to perform an eager loading as a workaround for this issue. To do so, just pass the name of the relation (i.e. `entities`) to the method:

```
 Capacitytype::find(124)->with('entities')->orderBy('name','asc')->lists('entities.name', 'entities.id');
```

Or else, you could first fetch the records, and then reformat it to match your usecase:

```
$list = Capacitytype::find(124)->entities()->orderBy('name','asc')->get()->toArray();
```

As such, you can *refine* the returned list of arrays, to match your *id* => *name* format (hence, a substitute for the `lists` method).

```
$refinedList = array();
foreach($list as $entity){
     $refinedList[$entity['id']] = $entity['name'];
}
```

And, there you go.

Comment: Ugh... I am unable to implement properly. The first solution: produces an empty collection. Surprisingly, the number of items in the collection (and items in my select field) seems to be right.

The second solution: produces no items in my select. I use the below code
@foreach($refinedList as $l)

  <option value="{{ URL::to('wybory-kandydaci?komitet='.@$l->entity->id) }}">{{$l->entity->name or '--'}}</option>

Comment: For the first approach, show the `dd($list)`, to see if it's empty collection in your controller or view.   
For the second approach, you should access the array item as such: 
First iterate as `@foreach($refinedList as $id => $name)`, then:
`<option  value="your url/" . {{ $id }}>{{ $name }}</option>`

Comment: in my controller I have `$list = Capacitytype::find(124)->entities()->orderBy('name','asc')->get()->toArray();`  when I do dd($list) I get only empty brackets: `[]`

Comment: Well, if you get `[]`, it means that the Capacitytype with id `124` doesn't have any `entities` related to it. Anyway, glad it worked for you.

Comment: "Capacitytype with id 124 doesn't have any entities related to it" - I confirm. They were deleted during my struggle. Sorry for that.